# Materials working in Eevee but not in Cycles (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine

I have this problem where colors that I have assigned in Geo Nodes do work in Eevee but not in Cycles.

Am I doing something stupidly wrong or is this some kind of a bug?

[image: Eevee]
Eevee example
[image: Cycles]
Cycles example
[image: Geometry Nodes setup]
Geometry Nodes setup
[image: Road Texture setup]
Road Texture setup

Yellow color is just a regular diffuse shader.

Comment: Please show the material itself. Some shader nodes are not compatible both either Eevee or Cycles.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally shared the post before I finished the whole question  but I have added the images now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a Cycles vs Eevee problem. Your setup seems to be accumulating extra, overlapping geometry as it goes on. Eevee is more forgiving about Z fighting, but Cycles is trying to be more accurate, which results in shading problems. Using `Merge by Distance` at appropriate points fixes it. You also don't seem to need neither the *Individual* tick on `Extrude Mesh` (unless you need the interior faces for some other reason) nor the `Separate Geometry`—*Point* node:

[image]

Adding another `Merge` node after you `Join Geometry` is also beneficial as it dramatically decreases the vertex amount from ~10k to ~1.6k:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem and the instructions were extremely clear and helpful.